# É necessário colocar o tipo do elemento dentro do try?

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

Ao otimizar meu código JDBC eu comecei a utilizar uma condição dentro do try.

```
    /** Função PreparedStatement stmt */
public PreparedStatement stmt;
/** Funçãoo ResultSet rs */
public ResultSet rs;

/** Método LoginDao - construtor */
public LoginDao() {
    super();
}

public long adiciona(Object object) {
    try {
        if (object.getClass() != new Login().getClass()) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        Login login = (Login) object;
        // Inserção Banco de Dados
        String sql = "INSERT INTO login "
                + "(email, senha, privilegio,ultimo_acesso,cpf)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        try(stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql)){}
        // prepared statement para inser��o
        stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        // criptografa os dados
        String emailCriptografado = new CriptografiaUniDirecional()
                .criptografar(login.getEmail());
        String senhaCriptografada = new CriptografiaUniDirecional()
                .criptografar(login.getSenha());
        System.out.println(emailCriptografado);
        System.out.println(senhaCriptografada);
        // verifica se este email ja esta cadastrado
        if (emailJaCadastrado(emailCriptografado) == false) {
            /** seta os valores */
            stmt.setString(1, emailCriptografado);
            stmt.setString(2, senhaCriptografada);
            stmt.setInt(3, login.getPrivilegio());
            // Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            stmt.setDate(4, data);
            stmt.setString(5, login.getCpf());
            stmt.execute();
        } else {
            stmt.close();
            return 1L;
        }
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return -1L;
}
```

Porem ele não vê a variável`PreparedStatement stmt;` não o reconhecendo como um tipo. Queria saber se tenho que declarar o tipo de da variável sendo que ela já esta declarada na minha classe.

Comment: Posta o código onde tu declara a variável.

Comment: public PreparedStatement stmt;
 public ResultSet rs; 

O código estava rodando legal. Porem ao tenta otimizar e colocar ele no try o objeto da erro

Comment: Cara, põe na pergunta todo o código relevante da tua classe. Só com uma linha de código não tem como te ajudar.

Comment: Coloca a declaração inteira do seu método @VictorHenrique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> É necessário colocar o tipo do elemento dentro do try?

Sim. Mas tem mais coisas para consertar no seu código.

Nessa linha tem dois problemas:

```
try(stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql)){}
```

O que você já havia desconfiado que gerava erro, que é a necessidade de declarar a variável com o seu tipo `PreparedStatement` e também o fato de você acidentalmente ter fechado o `try` logo de cara.

```
try(PreparedStatement stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql)){
```

Outra coisa importante a se notar é que não é necessário chamar o `close()` do `stmt`, pois o try with resources se encarrega disso.

Logo, seu código deveria ficar da seguinte forma:

```
try {
    if (object.getClass() != new Login().getClass()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    Login login = (Login) object;
    // Inserção Banco de Dados
    String sql = "INSERT INTO login "
            + "(email, senha, privilegio,ultimo_acesso,cpf)"
            + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    try(PreparedStatement stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql)){
        // prepared statement para inser��o
        stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        // criptografa os dados
        String emailCriptografado = new CriptografiaUniDirecional()
                .criptografar(login.getEmail());
        String senhaCriptografada = new CriptografiaUniDirecional()
                .criptografar(login.getSenha());
        System.out.println(emailCriptografado);
        System.out.println(senhaCriptografada);
        // verifica se este email ja esta cadastrado
        if (emailJaCadastrado(emailCriptografado) == false) {
            /** seta os valores */
            stmt.setString(1, emailCriptografado);
            stmt.setString(2, senhaCriptografada);
            stmt.setInt(3, login.getPrivilegio());
            // Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            stmt.setDate(4, data);
            stmt.setString(5, login.getCpf());
            stmt.execute();
        } else {
            return 1L;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return -1L;
}
```

Note que além disso o seu `try` de fora também precisa ou de um `catch()` ou de um `finally()`, mas é possível que você tenha omitido por se tratar de um exemplo.

Comment: Sim. Eu editei o código pra exemplificar o erro. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

[Nesse exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), do site da Oracle, ele implementa o `try-with-resources`.

Algumas coisas a serem observadas:

1. Esse recurso é disponível a partir da versao 1.7 do Java.
2. Ele coloca o tipo da variável dentro do parêntese.
3. Pelo que eu observei, a declaração da variável é feita por completo dentro do parêntese do `try` porque o **escopo dela é apenas dentro do try**. Ela não será utilizada fora. Por isso ela é declarada como `"resource"` do `try-with-resource`